# How to group object by key names that share a part of a name and convert it into array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm struggling to properly convert object into a grouped array of objects. Any suggestions how to get the expected results? The most important part is to group it by `HIGH_PRICE` and `LOW_PRICE` and create arrays of those grouped keys and values but it would be nice to additionally include name from what's left from similar part of the key for example if I have `HIGH_PRICE_QQQ` and `LOW_PRICE_QQQ` the name would be `QQQ`.

```
Example of the object to sort: 

const obj = {
  HIGH_PRICE_QQQ: "10000",
  HIGH_PRICE_WWW: "2000",
  LOW_PRICE_WWW: "200",
  HIGH_PRICE_EEE: "3000",
  LOW_PRICE_EEE: "300",
}
```

```
Expected result: 

const sorted = [
  {
    name: "QQQ",
    HIGH_PRICE_QQQ: "10000",
  },
  {
    name: "WWW",
    HIGH_PRICE_WWW: "2000",
    LOW_PRICE_WWW: "200",
  },
  {
    name: "EEE",
    HIGH_PRICE_EEE: "3000",
    LOW_PRICE_EEE: "300",
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `reduce` to group by the name. Finally to get the array format as you wanted use `Object.values` on the result.
`Object.entries` used to make `obj` iterable
`split` and `pop` used to extract the name which is last element of splitted array

```js
const obj = {
  HIGH_PRICE_QQQ: "10000",
  HIGH_PRICE_WWW: "2000",
  LOW_PRICE_WWW: "200",
  HIGH_PRICE_EEE: "3000",
  LOW_PRICE_EEE: "300",
}

let x = Object.values(Object.entries(obj).reduce((acc,[k,v])=> {
    let name = k.split("_").pop()
  acc[name]= acc[name] || {name}
  acc[name][k] = v
  return acc
},{}))

console.log(x)
```

Answer (score 1):

The below may be one possible solution to achieve the desired objective.

**Code Snippet**

```js
// helper method to extract the "name"
const getName = s => (
  s.includes("HIGH_PRICE_")
  ? s.split("HIGH_PRICE_").at(1)
  : s.includes("LOW_PRICE_")
    ? s.split("LOW_PRICE_").at(1)
    : s
);

// group the object by name
const groupByName = obj => (
  Object.values(            // extract only values of below result
    Object.entries(obj)     // extract key-value pairs from argument "obj"
    .reduce(                // iterate over key-values to generate intermediate result
      (fin, [k, v]) => ({   // "fin" is the accumulator / aggregator
        ...fin,
        [getName(k)]: (     // "name" is used as the key, and value is constructed
          [getName(k)] in fin
          ? {...fin[getName(k)], [k]: v}
          : { name: getName(k), [k]: v}
        )
      }),
      {}                    // "fin" is being set to empty-object at begining
    )
  )
);

const rawObj = {
  HIGH_PRICE_QQQ: "10000",
  HIGH_PRICE_WWW: "2000",
  LOW_PRICE_WWW: "200",
  HIGH_PRICE_EEE: "3000",
  LOW_PRICE_EEE: "300",
};

console.log(groupByName(rawObj));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

**Explanation**

Inline comments in the above snippet provide description of the various steps.